# How do you add or remove text to the end of many lines at once in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

e.g. I want to add a double quote to the end of a bunch of highlighted lines. Or I want to delete two characters from a bunch of highlighted lines. Is there a command for this? I know there is "M-x r t" for inserting a rectangle of text, but this only works if everything is lined up vertically, which isn't generally the case of the ends of lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can

1. save a keyboard macro with
   <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>(</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>,
   resp.
   <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>(</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>. Then invoke the macro with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>,
   <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>...
2. do a regex replacement with <kbd>M-C-%</kbd>. Replace `$` with `"`
   to add a double quote, replace `..$` with nothing to delete last two
   characters.

Comment: Or after recording the macro, do a C-u n C-x e where 'n' is the number of repeats he wants perhaps.

Comment: Aren't you missing a "C-n" in the macros there to go to the next line to prepare for the next execution of the macro?

Comment: How do you put keystrokes in your answer? Does that also work for questions?

Comment: @allyourcode: Use `<kbd>...</kbd>`. It works for questions, too. It does not work for comments, though.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`replace-regexp` `$` `"` should work, but I'm not sure if `replace-regexp` respects mark.

Comment: You can always `narrow-to-region` and operate on the whole narrowed buffer without risk of destroying lines outside of your original highlinght (`C-x n n` and `C-x n w` to revert narrowing).

Comment: `replace-regexp` can also be used for the other task (deleting the 2 last characters). Replace "..$" with nothing to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more visual way, see the results in every line as you type them in one line.

Grab a recent copy of [YASnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) and add to your `.emacs`

```elisp
(require 'yasnippet)

(defun yas/add-to-end-of-lines-snippet ()
  (interactive)
  (when (region-active-p)
    (let ((snippet (replace-regexp-in-string "$" "$1" (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end)))))
      (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
      (yas/expand-snippet snippet))))
```

Now select a region and type `M-x add-to-end-of-lines-snippet`.